# managing users in socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I am writing a game with socket.io, and to manage the 2 players in the game I have something that looks like this:

```
let user1 = 1;
let user2 = 2;
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    if (user1 === 1) user1 = socket;
    else if (user2 === 2) user2 = socket;

    socket.on('user_does_something', function(){
        if (user1 === socket) {
            //do something for user1
        }
        if (user2 === socket) {
            //do something for user2
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        if (user1 === socket) user1 = 1;
        if (user2 === socket) user2 = 2;
    });

});
```

it works, but it seems like a terrible way to do it, is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach isn't scalable as you are currently limited to only two concurrent users, this means if you wish to implement some form of lobby system even if you are limiting two to a game you can only have one concurrent game running.

instead I would suggest the use of a `Map()` which you can use to store client objects which hold information about the currently connected client. You can use properties of the socket object such as `socket.id` to form identifiers for each user. Another note is we already know the connected user the event has been derived from as we pass in the `socket` object so when user one emits and event we can find which user emitted the event using the `id` property of the object as seen below.

```
socket.on('user_does_something', function(){
    if (user1 === socket) {
        //do something for user1
    }
    if (user2 === socket) {
        //do something for user2
    }
});
```

This function could be refactored to be

```
let connectedUserMap = new Map();

io.on('connection', function(socket){

let connectedUserId = socket.id;
connectedUserMap.set(socket.id, { status:'online'});

    socket.on('user_does_something', function(){
        //do something
    });
}
```

This way of handling users is superior as you already know the connected user and it reduces the logic needed to identify who the event is derived from.

I can write a better example if needed, but this should help you improving your code.

Update:

backend code

```
let connectedUserMap = new Map();

io.on('connection', function(socket){

let connectedUserId = socket.id;

//add property value when assigning user to map
connectedUserMap.set(socket.id, { status:'online', name: 'none' });

    socket.on('recieveUserName', function(data){
        //find user by there socket in the map the update name property of value
        let user = connectedUserMap.get(connectedUserId);
        user.name = data.name;
    });
}
```

frontend emit:

```
emit('recieveUserName', {
//normally this would be dynamically added based on user input, but for examples sake
  name: 'user1'
});
```

Long form example with two extra functions for clarity:

```
let connectedUserMap = new Map();

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    let connectedUserId = socket.id;

    //add property value when assigning user to map
    connectedUserMap.set(socket.id, { status:'online', name: 'none' });


    socket.on('user_does_something', function(){
        //get access to the user currently being used via map.
        let user = connectedUserMap.get(connectedUserId);

        //do something.

    });

    //sets the user name for the user.
    socket.on('recieveUserName', function(data){
        //find user by there socket in the map the update name property of value
        let user = connectedUserMap.get(connectedUserId);
        user.name = data.name;
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        //get access to the user currently being used via map.
        let user = connectedUserMap.get(connectedUserId);
        user.status = 'offline';
    });

    socket.on('someEventForAEveryone', function (data) {
        //data.msg - message to be output
        io.emit('message', "this is a test");
    });

    //example of sending another user a message
    //https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/3f257d0bb813e2c8c476 - reference
    socket.on('sendOtherClientMessage', function (data) {
        //data.id - the user to emit to.
        if(connectedUserMap.has(data.id)){
            socket.broadcast.to(data.id).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
        } else {
            console.log("Client is currently not connected.");
        }
    })

};
```

Comment: so lets say the user sends their name and i want to assign it to that user's name variable in socket.on('name', fucntion(name){ ... }); what would that look like?

Comment: I have updated my answer showing how you would assign a name to a user using the structure I outlined above. @Orion

Comment: @Orion I just updated it where I have completely rewritten your existing code and also added two functions for some more clarity, hopefully this gets you started :-)

Comment: Another question, how would I remove that user from the map on disconnect?

Comment: @Orion you can use `connectedUserMap.delete(connectedUserId)` to remove an entry with there socketId.

Comment: @lix - How would we find a user with his Id to send a message specific to the user if he is online. Because as per your code user id is socket id which is not true generally.